# Python - How to create a dictionary list from another list which having two keys with multiple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary list from another list which has two keys with multiple values as follows:

```
contact_items = [{'type': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
                 'name': ['john', 'SCANIA', 'MARK']}]

list1 = ''
list2 = ''
list3 = []
test_dict = {}

for item in contact_items:
    list1 = item['type']
    list2 = item['name']

test_dict = {}

for k in list1:
    for l in list2:
        test_dict['type'] = k
        test_dict['name'] = l
        list3.append(test_dict)

print(list3)
```

The above code is not returning the dictionary list as expected.

Outputs:

```
[{'type': 'value3', 'name': 'MARK'}, {'type': 'value3', 'name': 'MARK'}, {'type': 'value3', 'name': 'MARK'}, {'type': 'value3', 'nam
e': 'MARK'}, {'type': 'value3', 'name': 'MARK'}, {'type': 'value3', 'name': 'MARK'}, {'type': 'value3', 'name': 'MARK'}, {'type': 'v
alue3', 'name': 'MARK'}, {'type': 'value3', 'name': 'MARK'}]
```

Expected:

```
result=[{'type':'value1','name':'john'},
{'type':'value2','name':'SCANIA'},
{'type':'value3','name':'MARK'}]
```

Comment: You're putting the same dict in the list multiple times. And you're assigning different values to the same variables in your first loop. And you're iterating through every combination of items in `list1` and `list2` in your nested loop.

Comment: @khelwood i tired the way as i mentioned, let me know if you giving the solution with your comments.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting the same dict in the list multiple times. And you're assigning different values to the same variables in your first loop. And you're iterating through every combination of items in `list1` and `list2` in your nested loop.

Here is a way to get the outcome you specified from the input you specified:

```
types = contact_items[0]['type']
names = contact_items[0]['name']
list3 = [{'type': t, 'name': n} for (t,n) in zip(types, names)]
```

See [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 0):

This is very trivial. Look up list comprehension and dictionary comprehension.

```
result = [{"type": contact_items[0]["type"][i], 
"name": contact_items[0]["name"][i]} 
for i in range(len(contact_items[0]["name"])) ]
```

Neater.

```
items = contact_items[0]

result = [{"type": items["type"][i], "name": items["name"][i]} for i in range(len(items["name"]))]
result
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) in combination with [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to achieve this.

```
result = [
    {"name": name, "type": type}
    for type, name in zip(*contact_items[0].values())
]
```

Comment: I can also write a short solution `[dict(zip(contact_items[0].keys(), values)) for values in zip(*contact_items [0].values())]`, but it would be better to help him understand what went wrong with his code, and why this code is better. In this case a reference to [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) and [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) would probably help understand your code.